# gcc on mac osx does not understand OpenMP flag

Tags: macos, gcc, compilation, openmp

I am asking the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489813/compiling-openmp-macports-gcc-and-eclipse-cdt).  However, the answers given there did not get me past my problem, and that question was asked a few years ago, so I'm thinking perhaps things have changed.

When I try to compile on my Mac OSX (High Sierra 10.13.4) for OpenMP, I get the error:

```
>$ gcc -fopenmp omp_accum_sum.cpp
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

AFAICT from the info mac ports gives me, I have the latest available versions of gcc, clang and OpenMP installed:

```
    >$ port installed gcc7
    The following ports are currently installed:
      gcc7 @7.3.0_1 (active)
    >$ port installed libomp
    The following ports are currently installed:
      libomp @0.0_246703
      libomp @0.0_261249
      libomp @0.0_264411+universal
      libomp @3.9.0_1+universal
      libomp @3.9.1_0+universal
      libomp @5.0.1_0+universal (active)
    >$ port installed clang-6.0
    The following ports are currently installed:
       clang-6.0 @6.0.0_0+analyzer+libstdcxx (active)
```

I've seen a few things around the internet about pointing the gcc command to the correct gcc, but if that's what I have to do, I have not even been able to figure out where the correct gcc is.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to use -Xclang -fopenmp instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case anyone is interested, I found a good compiler with `/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-7`.

This took alot of hunting and pecking.  Seems to me that mac ports would have some systematic way of finding things like this.  If anyone can say what that is, I would still be grateful.